# Automatically subscribe to an observable within an Rx stream

Tags: kotlin, rx-java

I have the following code:

```
Completable.fromCallable { messagesBO.deleteAllGroupsForMessage(messageId) }
    .andThen { Completable.fromAction { messagesBO.storeMessageGroups(messageToGroups) }.subscribe() }
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(
        {
        },
        { error ->  }
    ))
```

I have a second Completable:

```
Completable.fromAction
```

and I need to subscribe to this in order for the function inside fromAction to run. But this seems to not be a clean way of doing this.

I don't necessarily need to use a Completable as I'm not returning anything in the onComplete. Is there some other way to call a function and have it automatically subscribed to? I could in fact have multiple andThen(s) and would like to chain them together.

UPDATE:

Here is one solution, although I'm not convinced it's the best:

```
Observable.fromCallable { messagesBO.deleteAllGroupsForMessage(messageId) }
    .flatMapCompletable { Completable.fromAction { messagesBO.storeMessageGroups(messageToGroups) } }
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(
        {
        },
        { error -> }
    ))
```

Comment: remove the .subscribe() on the nested Completable, you don't need it. The entire rx chain needs only 1 subscribe()

Comment: *I don't necessarily need to use a Completable as I'm **not returning anything*** that is exactly why you *do* use a Completable

Comment: @TimCastelijns I removed that but the code inside of the fromAction never gets executed. It will only execute if the subscribe is added. NOTE: the storeMessageGroups function does not return a Completable, if that is what you are assuming.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that it's simpler than I thought. Just using map will automatically run the code without any need to create an observable:

```
Observable.fromCallable { messagesBO.deleteAllGroupsForMessage(messageId) }
    .map { messagesBO.storeMessageGroups(messageToGroups) }
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(
        {

        },
        { error ->  }
    )
```